# Docker can not install yarn packages

Tags: node.js, docker

I am trying to transform my NodeJs app into a Docker container, but during the "yarn" command, the container is having errors while installing the dependencies. I already removed unnecessary dependencies and cleaned node cache, but it still having this error.

There's the error:

```
 => ERROR [4/5] RUN yarn                                                                       21.3s
------
 > [4/5] RUN yarn:
#0 0.772 yarn install v1.22.19
#0 0.887 [1/4] Resolving packages...
#0 1.074 [2/4] Fetching packages...
#0 6.223 error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/follow-redirects/-/follow-redirects-1.15.2.tgz: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.yarnpkg.com".
#0 6.223 info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/usr/app/yarn-error.log".
#0 6.223 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c yarn]: exit code: 1
```

I tried removing unnecessary dependencies and cleaning the node cache, also deleted the node_modules folder and re-installed the project in my machine, and it worked just fine, while Docker was having this errors.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./

RUN yarn

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '1'

services:
  app:
    container_name: nodejs-backend
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    command: yarn start
```

.dockerignore

```
node_modules
```

I am also starting the container with this command: `docker-compose up`

Comment: I would simplify your Dockerfile to identify the faulty step ... keep in mind the commands inside Dockerfile are essentially the same commands you can issue yourself on a fresh OS install ... naturally it helps to be developing your code on an OS which matches the OS inside your Dockerfile that way you can issue those same commands from a terminal directly on your laptop or any host ... its hard to troubleshoot this without seeing the entire simplified Dockerfile

Comment: Hey, Scott. I edited my question with the Dockerfile and all the others config files related to Docker I have in the project.